# How to deploy angulardart 5.2 properly for production?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

On the angulardart official website, I cannot find any docs related to production deployment. I prefer command line way, so far I find out I can do `webdev build` to generate a `build/` directory. But there are still some more questions:

1. I want to clarify what files I should deploy to the production server. I think they should be `favicon.ico, index.html, main.dart.js, styles.css` 4 files, right?
2. Why does it generate `.build.manifest, .packages, packages/`? Two files and one directory which contains many directories and files. They are just confusing me. This is for production. Why do I ever want to have those files? Should I write a deploy script to simply auto-remove them?
3. It seems the generated `main.dart.js` is a minimized js file. But why are there many useless newlines in it? How to get rid of those useless newlines properly by using angulardart way? I can do that with Gulp, but I don't want to use Gulp if Dart can handle this.
4. How to minimize html and css files properly by using angulardart way? for example, `index.html` and `styles.css`. Again, I can do that with Gulp, but I don't want to use Gulp if Dart can handle this.

Comment: also curious about .packages and packages/. Maybe they are there to help debug production stuff, but dunno

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find some of official doc :

https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/deployment

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. I didn't find it before. After reading it, it still doesn't answer my 4 questions . Especially, why does `webdev build` want to generate useless directories and files. I just don't get the idea at all. It's supposed to build files for production only. Cheers.

Comment: I suppose these files are generated for modules assets. In my project, all assets are stored in packages/my_app/asset. Maybe some of these module files are needed or maybe there are not excluded from the module build config...